Why does tr offsetTop differ between Firefox and Chrome when tr or td has a border?
In the following example, the offsetTop of tr rows in a table returns different results for Firefox and Chrome(Brave version) when a td within the tr has a border top and bottom.
I was expecting the first tr to have an offsetTop of 0 but in Firefox it is 1 because of the border width. At least when there are no borders the offsetTop is 0.
Having easy access to the offsetTop of all tr in a table regardless of the number of tbody elements they may be contained within, and the fact that the tr.rowIndex is automatically updated as rows are added/deleted/re-ordered makes table very useful.
Is this simply a browser difference (or error in Firefox) and is there a way to adjust the CSS to get a 0 or get a 1 in Chrome?
Perhaps I'm overlooking the obvious, but thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.


let
   tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
   l = tr.length
;
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++ )
  console.log(`${tr[i].offsetTop} ${tr[i].offsetHeight}`);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;

}
table, tbody, tr {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
td {
  border-color: transparent transparent rgb(221,232,237) transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1rem 0 0.1rem 0;

}
<table>
<colgroup>
 <col class="track">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
 <tr><td>Row index 0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Row index 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Row index 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>



Firefox
1 25
26 25
51 25

Chrome (Brave)
0 25
25 25
50 25

The results are the same if move the border to the tr only.


let
   tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
   l = tr.length
;
for (let i = 0; i < l; i++ )
  console.log(`${tr[i].offsetTop} ${tr[i].offsetHeight}`);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;

}
table, tbody, tr {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

tr {
  border-color: transparent transparent rgb(221,232,237) transparent;
  border-width: 0.1rem 0 0.1rem 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
<table>
<colgroup>
 <col class="track">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
 <tr><td>Row index 0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Row index 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Row index 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>



